# Enabling logging for rabbit mq server within a docker image

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am installing rabbit mq server within docker using the steps mentioned @ https://hub.docker.com/r/_/rabbitmq/ .

The installation went through fine, got my rabbitmq working perfectly fine.

I am unable to find the rabbit mq logs.

How to control and turn on the logging?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `docker logs rabbitmq_container_id` to show rabbitmq logs.

or

`tail -f /var/lib/docker/rabbitmq_container_id/rabbitmq_container_id.logs`